# Pandas - create mean column based on cell value

Tags: pandas

I have this concatenated dataframe:

```
                team  home  rank_home team   away rank_away
          0     team1   70   1        team2   60  1
          1     team2   60   2        team1   40  2
```

---

Now I need to create a 'mean' column ((home+away)/2), but I can'y do it row-wise. How so?

---

Desired result:

```
                team  home   rank_home team  away  rank_away  team   mean  rank_mean
          0     team1   70   1         team2   60  1          team2    60  1
          1     team2   60   2         team1   40  2          team1    55  2
```

Comment: I assume that a row holds information about a match and `home` and `away` are final scores of each match. Do you want to average the final scores for each team? If so, this won't have the same structure, because a row would constitute a team, not a match.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's assume your data looks like this:

[image]

Then you have to separate the home and away scores and merge them:

```
# separate
scores_home = df[['team_home', 'score_home']].rename(columns={'team_home': 'team'})
scores_away = df[['team_away', 'score_away']].rename(columns={'team_away': 'team'})

# join on team
scores = pd.merge(scores_home, scores_away, on='team').set_index('team')

# compute mean scores
scores['score_mean'] = scores[['score_home', 'score_away']].mean(axis=1)

scores
```

[image]

If you want, you could join this result back onto your original dataframe, but I don't think that makes a lot of sense.

Answer (score 1):

Divide the datframe into two using the iloc accessor. Merge them back with the rows aligned. and calc mean

```
 g=pd.merge(df.iloc[:,:3],df.iloc[:,3:], how='left', on='team')#From your datframe
#g=pd.merge(df.iloc[:,:3],df.iloc[:,3:], how='left', left_on='team', right_on='team.1')# because I copied and pasted df, second column was named team.1
 df['mean']=g[['home','away']].agg('mean',1)

     team  home  rank_home team.1  away  rank_away  mean
0  team1    70          1  team2    60          1  55.0
1  team2    60          2  team1    40          2  60.0
```